# I keep getting an "Oops! Something Bad Happened" when I try to merge two accounts on Data Explorer

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer, merge-accounts

I logged in on the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) using my Stack Exchange account, the same I already use on other Stack Exchange sites, but I got logged in with a different user account. So, I tried to merge https://data.stackexchange.com/users/20598/kiam-la-luno (the new account) with https://data.stackexchange.com/users/5248/kiamlaluno using the [*contact us*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link, which redirects me to Meta Stack Exchange. After I fill the links for the accounts to merge, I keep getting an error message, and requesting the merge fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you be redirected to a error page or just be shown a error message ("Profile links must be for Stack Exchange sites") - either way, Data explorer, although having an address which makes it look like a typical SE site, is not really a SE site - and the topic called "I need to merge user profiles" applies to the accounts on some real SE site. (this could be a reason why you get the error page).

I guess you should use "other" in such cases and note that you would like to merge two accounts on the Data explorer.

Comment: I added a Google email address to my global account and used *Log in using Google* on Data Explorer. I could not merge the two accounts, but my display name is the same as on the other Stack Exchange sites.